# VS 2012: Konfiguration Combo too Small

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to change the size of this combo?

[image: Combobox]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's possible.

> Click on "Standard Toolbar Option" -> "Add or Remove Buttons" ->
> select "Customize"
>
> In opened new window under "Command" tab scroll down and highlight
> "Solution Configuration" -> Click on "Modify Selection" and change the
> width accordingly

Follow the below screen print in `Visual Studio 2010`

[image]
[image]
[image]